# Issues with SP Online mapped drives in File Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-online, webdav, windows, file-explorer

Hope you are well. Using the file explorer is widely preferred is widely preferred in our organisation - and we use WebDav to be able to access file repositories via file explorer. When trying to access SP Online mapped drives via File Explorer we have been getting intermittent error messages such as:

- "\domain.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites... is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. A device attached to the system is not functioning"
- "Windows cannot access \domain.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites... - Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose"
- Or sometimes no error message but the folder in File Explorer will just say "This folder is empty" (when it's not in reality).

The issues are intermittent, it can be fine for a whole month and but then just be absolutely horrendous for two weeks. One thing I have picked up on is that these issues are network wide: so if I am experiencing the issue, 100% my colleagues also couldn't access at the same time. The issue is limited to just SP Online repositories, it works perfectly fine with SharePoint 2010 for example.

- We are currently going through a file migration to SP Online. Could it be some sort of network level throttling due to this? However SP Online sites themselves can be accessed, making me think this is unlikely - and typically throttling is done on the account level as far as I know.
- WebDav 'incompatibility' to SP Online seems to be the most likely culprit from my research, but is WebDav at fault if it's an intermittent network level problem?

I have read various similar threads and we have tried things such as adding "ourdomain.sharepoint.com" to the trusted sites, we have tried with our VPN on and off, we have tried making sure we are authenticated in IE. Nothing seems to have helped this issue. Would appreciate any input.

Comment: You do need to authenticate in the browser, using IE, to have WebDAV work. You should look at abandoning WebDAV as IE will no longer be supported with SPO -- I wouldn't expect this form of accessing SPO to be available for much longer. Switch to using the OneDrive client, instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TrevorSeward appreciate the input - yeah that's my inkling as well from speaking to Microsoft. One Drive does seem like the avenue to pursue. (I hope the following does not breach any rules, but for anyone in the future who is lurking and finds this thread if they have the same issues, I would like to point them also to my Reddit crosspost: https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/j55d68/issues_with_sp_online_mapped_drives_in_file/) - which in short agrees with Trevor's assessment